# Riemann Sums in Work Questions

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

So given the question "A conical tank of radius $5\mathrm{m}$ and height $10\mathrm{m}$ is filled with a liquid whose density is $3.42 \mathrm{kg/m^3}$. how much work is needed to lift the liquid out of the tank?"
The answer can be found by taking the integral $$\int_{0}^{10} 3.42 \cdot \pi \cdot 9.8 \cdot (10-h) \cdot (h/2)^2\ dh $$
However, I'm confused about one thing. The equation 
$$ (10-h)\cdot (h/2)^2\cdot 9.8\cdot 3.42\cdot \pi \cdot dh $$
gives us the work required to lift a disc of height $dh$ out of the tank.
Why does the integral of this expression within the limits 0-10 give us the work required to lift all the water out of the tank?

Thanks,
newtondiedavirgin

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! That is because the total work is the sum (integral) of the elementary works.

Comment: Youve split the cylinder with height $10$, into a bunch of disks with thickness $dh$, so you have to sum them all, from $h=0$, to $h=10$...

Answer (score 1):

a) the tank is a cone with the vertex at the top, and base on ground;
b) $h$ is actually the distance from the vertex, the height being $H=10-h$, at which the radius is $h/2$;
c) the integrand is the potential energy acquired by disk $\rho \pi r^2 dH$ at height $H$;
d) the integral is the work needed to fill the tank (= potential energy), i.e. for the liquid to start and pour from the top, with the substitution $h$ for $H$.